# Are there any wallets (phantom, solflare, etc) that can be integrated into an electron app and used to send transactions?

Tags: wallet, phantom, webapp

I am able to integrate Phantom and other wallets with my web-app using the @wallet-adapter. I am now trying to turn the web app into an electron app. Is it still possible to connect it to a software wallet like Phantom?

Answer (score 1):

You might check out Ledger (https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-live). They have Electron integration with Solana, but integration with Phantom is just copy/pasting your seed phrase, so I suspect the answer is no, otherwise they would have a better way to move your wallet over by now.